# Letters for chinese wedding invitation

Tags: mandarin, characters, pinyin, traditional-characters

I'm looking for the (traditional) Chinese letters for 'he fu tong qing' (pin yin transcription), which should mean something like 'the whole family invited' in the context of a wedding invitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

阖府统请 (Simplified Chinese)

闔府統請 (Traditional Chinese)

Comment: I did wish to upvote your answer, but what the heck do you mean by "standard/old writing"? Traditional Chinese characters are used in some places (e.g. Taiwan and Hong Kong) and the simplified ones are used in some others. You don't need a "special reason" to use traditional Chinese characters.

Comment: @倪阔乐: It's a wedding invitation for a Chinese family that mainly use traditional characters :)

Comment: I sense some point of view pushing here from the answerer's part. I've changed the answer to use standard terminology in English.

Comment: Even in these modern days, many people still use Traditional Chinese characters for formal stuff like wedding invitations, I've never seen a wedding invitation using Simplified Chinese yet.